# I want to build a Power BI Connector to allow users to access my query engine as a data source. Do I need to build a custom ODBC driver for this?

Tags: powerbi, odbc

At my work, we are working on making features which would enable a user to connect to our query engine's data sources from Power BI. For this as far as I'm aware I need to build a custom connector.

Since Power BI doesn't support JDBC we're unable to directly connect to it. Currently we're exploring if we can make a HTTP connection but if that doesn't work, we'll probably have to build an ODBC connector.

So far we've tried to see if we can find wrappers or SDKs to abstract some of the lower level programming parts of ODBC drivers and explore alternate connection methods.  We've made little progress however.

Comment: Why don't you use this: https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/use-your-custom-jdbc-driver-with-microsoft-power-bi ?

Comment: Their download links are buggy and don't work lol

Comment: Why don't you use `ODBC`? `ODBC` works for C,C++,Java etc. while `JDBC` works only with Java. Where are your data stored? On a database? CSV on filesystem?